# C4 template just disappeared

Tags: xcode, c4

Yesterday there was a background update of my XCode (5.0.2) running and since the C4 template disappeared. 
Also reinstalling C4 fails. 
Any ideas what's up? How can I remove C4 installation completely in order to reinstall afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the installer doesn't persist between versions of Xcode. You'll have to run the installer again, this happened to me last week as well.

Comment: but my problem was when running the installer again it fails. that's why I'm confused.

Comment: how does it fail? i installed cleanly on mavericks the other day with an upgrade to Xcode 5.0.2... Does the installer just say "fail"?